# Access user session objects from another thread, how to make it?

Tags: java, session, servlets

How can I access a user session objects from another thread?

I want to **delete some users** on a regular basis. I can just delete them from the database, but **some user can be logged in**. So I want to invalidate his session if its exists. How can I find and **invalidate his session** using his userId?

As I understand a servlet container has some hash-like structure to store "sessionId" => "UserSession" mappings. Can I access them? Can I somehow store userIds as keys in that structure?

The alternative which I don't like, is to check the database for user object existence in the beginning of every user request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can track your sessions by implementing [SessionListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and registering it in your web.xml.

Answer (score 4):

The functionality you were looking for [existed but was removed](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionContext.html) due to security concerns.

You should be able to recreate it by implementing a [HttpSessionListener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to create your own record of what active sessions exist.